# How to stop hard coding text attribute error in Android app development Eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Everytime I add any element whether it is Text or a Button I edit the text but it always gives me hard coding text attribute error, it asks me to add @string. I always then ask it to ignore it. But is there any way through which I cannot get this error.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: You should ALWAYS use strings.xml! bad, bad guy!

Comment: This warning is created to make you code properly. You'd better add string resource than disable it.

Comment: I will good for your programming career, if you follow the standards of coding. The warning specially indicating that. So, try defining the values dynamically using res folders instead of hard coding that.

Comment: @DoctororDrive : how can I add it to string resource? What should I code for it?

Comment: Please see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html

Comment: Thank you all for the help, and I have learn't adding things to string :) works great now!! Stay Blessed ^_^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Window> Preferences > Android > Lint Error Checking > Hardcoded Text > Severity : Ignore >
Apply > Ok

Answer (score 0):

Right click on project > Properties > Android Lint Preferences > HardcodedText > Severity: Ignore